# why I am getting undefined result with for loop function?

Tags: javascript

why this code return undefined 
I can't spot the reason

```
function findShort(s){
  let splitted = s.split(' ');
  let result = splitted[0].length ;
  let looped
  for (var i=0 ; i++ ; i<splitted.length){ 
    looped = splitted[i].length;
    if (looped < result) {return looped}else {return result }}
};
console.log(findShort("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"));
```

I am supposed to get numbers of smallest word

Comment: The order of the statements in your for-loop is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop `condition` and `increment` are inverted:

```
for (var i=0 ; i++ ; i<splitted.length){ ...
```

should instead be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) { ...
```

You also have to fix your looping code as it returns in both branches of you  inner `if` statement, which means only a single iteration will run.

If you want to return the length of the smallest word, do this:

```js
function findShort(s) {
  let splitted = s.split(' ');
  let result = splitted[0].length;
  for (let i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) { 
    const looped = splitted[i].length;
    if (looped < result) {
      result = looped;
    }
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(findShort("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"));
```

Or shorter using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
function findShortest(s) {
  return s.split(/\s+/).reduce((out, x) => x.length < out ? x.length : out, s.length);
};
console.log(findShortest('bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop implementation is wrong, it is supposed to be:

```
for (var i=0; i<splitted.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of `condition` and `increment`  is wrong in you `for loop` as well as the code inside the loop,

it will check for the first element only as you have a `return` in all conditions.

Here's the correct one

```js
function findShort(s) {
 let splitted = s.split(' ');
 let result = splitted[0].length;
 let looped
 for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
  looped = splitted[i].length;
  if (looped < result) { result = looped }
 }
 return result;
};

console.log(findShort("bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps"));
```